# CSS animate each list item seperate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code snippet (HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery).
The question is about the `<ul>` with the class `items-list` in the right div with the class `list-div`.
I managed to animate the whole list, however, I tried to animate each list item to fly in its ending position. I know I can use a simple jQuery with a delayed animation, like

```
var delay = 0;
$("#list-to-animate li").each(function() {
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({"top" : "+=30px"}, "fast");
    delay += 200;
});
```

But this will not work with my whole JavaScript that checks if the element is actually on the screen.
I am also struggling with how to position the `li` elements properly, so they are outside of the `list-div`.
Can someone help me to animate each `li` the way the whole list now is, so the fly in successively?
PS: I am not sure if the embedded video works, if not just scroll down.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
    //prevent direct jump to the linked element
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
});


var slideIndex = 0;

// run TWO slideshows, one for each slider
showSlides(0);
showSlides(1);

// give your slider function parameter of index
function showSlides(index) {
  var i;
  // select the particular slider and THEN its slides
  var sliderBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("instagram-slideshow")[index];
  var slides = sliderBlock.getElementsByClassName("slide");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  // after timeout run appropriate function again
  setTimeout(function() {showSlides(index)}, 2000);
}
(function($) {
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
    
      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
    
    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };
    
})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allModifications = $(".half-width-content");


//make all elements visible that are directly visible
allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open"); 
    el.find(".list-div").addClass("open"); 
  } 
});


//make elements visible that get scrolled into the viewport
win.scroll(function(event) {
  
  allModifications.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.find(".half-width-text").addClass("open"); 
      el.find(".list-div").addClass("open"); 
    } 
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;    
  flex-direction:row;    
  height:100vh;
  background-color: beige;
}
.container > div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.container > div > a > .dot{
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s linear;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 10%;
  z-index: 101;
    height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container > div > a  > .dot > .arrow-down {
  transition: border .2s linear;
  position: absolute;
  top:11%;
  left: 24%;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover{
  background: black;
}
.container > div > a .dot:hover > .arrow-down{
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.container > div > a > .dot > .arrow-down{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container > div .content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.full-width {
  width:100%;              
}
.half-width {
  width:50%;
}

.video-iframe.fullsize{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.list{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .instagram-slideshow > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 150%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text > h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .half-width-text.open{
  visibility: visible;
  top: 50%;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .list-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .list-div{
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 120%;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}

.half-width > .half-width-content > .list-div.open{
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-directin: row;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third{
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.full-width > .content > .third-parent > .third > .middle-text{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full-width">
<iframe class="video-iframe fullsize" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5C7r6HhALuk"" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <a href="#section2">
      <span class="dot">
        <i class="arrow-down"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width" id="section2">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="half-width-text">
        <h1>Headline</h1>
        <div class="text-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="1">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
        <img class="slide" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="slide" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="instagram-slideshow" id="2">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Hello">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=Bye">
        <img class="slide" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=BLA">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-width">
    <div class="half-width-content">
      <div class="list-div">
        <ul class="items-list">
          <li>A</li>
          <li>B</li>
          <li>C</li>
          <li>D</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="content">
       <div class="third-parent">
         <div class="third" id="one">
           <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
          </div>
        <div class="third" id="two">
          <div class="middle-text">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>A</li>
              <li>B</li>
              <li>C</li>
              <li>D</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third" id="three">
          <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: animate is an async operation, you can build up a recursive function with the animate callback to archive your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom property to pass the delay to each element with Javascript. You can use keyframes or simple transitions triggered by classes or aria-attributes (even better).

```js
/* Simplified for reading */

LISTELEMENTS.each ...
  ELEMENT.style.setProperty('--item-animiation-delay', ELEMENTINDEX * 100 +"ms");
```

```css
@keyframes fade-to-left {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: 100%;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}


.ListItem {
  animation-name: fade-to-left;
  animation-duration: 600ms;
  animation-delay: var(--item-animiation-delay, 300ms);
}
```

Comment: Do i need to remove the actual animation?

Comment: The keyframe inside the snippet provide a simple slide-to-left with fade in. If you want to keep and use it, yes you should remove all other animations. Also note that custom properties are not supported by IE 11<

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```
    ul.items-list {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.items-list li {
        position: absolute;
    }
    ul.items-list li:nth-child(1) { top: 500px; transition: top .2s; opacity: 0; }
    ul.items-list li:nth-child(2) { top: 500px; transition: top .2s .2s; opacity: 0; }
    ul.items-list li:nth-child(3) { top: 500px; transition: top .2s .4s; opacity: 0; }
    ul.items-list li:nth-child(4) { top: 500px; transition: top .2s .6s; opacity: 0; }

    ul.items-list.bindDynamicclass li:nth-child(1) { top: 0; opacity: 1; }
    ul.items-list.bindDynamicclass li:nth-child(2) { top: 20px; opacity: 1; }
    ul.items-list.bindDynamicclass li:nth-child(3) { top: 40px; opacity: 1; }
    ul.items-list.bindDynamicclass li:nth-child(4) { top: 60px; opacity: 1; }
```

Bind some class(.bindDynamicclass) to ul.items-list on scroll using js.

Comment: so simply add to the li the class bindDynamicclass?